# mysql null pointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

I am running a scheduler in which email is generated automatically. I have set crontab file in Linux window and when I try to execute the scheduler I get this error message :

```
Exception excp conn: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have imported all the necessary libraries as you can see me source code
need urgent support

```
package Hosting;
Hosting.ScheduleMessanger

public class ScheduleMessanger {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        Statement stmt1 = null;
        ResultSet rset1 = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        int i = 0;int _fesc_ = 0;int _nesc_ = 0;int _lesc_ = 0;
        String Query = "";String Query1 = "";String EmailText = "";String CustEmail = "";
        String connect_string = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/dbname?user=user&password=passw";


        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect_string);
        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
          conn = null;
          System.out.println("Exception excp conn: "+excp.getMessage());
          return;
        }

        Query = "Query goes here";
        try
        {
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          rset = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
          while (rset.next())
          {
            EmailText = "Dear All <br>";
            EmailText = EmailText + "The complain #"+rset.getString(2)+" is still un-resolved. <br>";
            EmailText = EmailText + "This mail is being generated to take the matter in your knowledge. <br><br>";

            EmailText = EmailText + "Complain By : " + rset.getString(3) + " <br>";
            EmailText = EmailText + "Complaint Type : " + rset.getString(4) + "<br>";
            EmailText = EmailText + "Priority Level : " + rset.getString(21) + "<br>";
            EmailText = EmailText + "Problem Description : " + rset.getString(24) + "<br>";

            EmailText = EmailText+"Sincerely, <br>";

            _fesc_ = _nesc_ = _lesc_ = 0;
            CustEmail = "";
            Query1 = "Second Query";
            try
            {
              stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
              rset1 = stmt1.executeQuery(Query1);
              if (rset1.next())
              {
                _fesc_ = rset1.getInt(1);
                _nesc_ = rset1.getInt(2);
                _lesc_ = rset1.getInt(3);
              }
              rset1.close();
              stmt1.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              _fesc_ = _nesc_ = _lesc_ = 0;
            }

            if (_fesc_ == 0)
            {
              if (rset.getString(10).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(10) + ",";
              }
              if (rset.getString(11).length() > 1)
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(11) + ",";
              }
              if (rset.getString(12).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(12) + ",";
              }
              i = SendEmail("Complain Escalation", "First Complain Escalation", EmailText, CustEmail);
              if (i == 1) 
              {
                UpdateEscalationTable(rset.getInt(1), 1, conn);
              }
            }
            else if (_nesc_ == 0)
            {
              if (rset.getString(13).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(13) + ",";
              }
              if (rset.getString(14).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(14) + ",";
              }
              if (rset.getString(15).length() > 1)
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(15) + ",";
              }
              i = SendEmail("Complain Escalation", "Second Complain Escalation", EmailText, CustEmail);
              if (i == 1) 
              {
                UpdateEscalationTable(rset.getInt(1), 2, conn);
              }
            }
            else if (_lesc_ == 0)
            {
              if (rset.getString(16).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(16) + ",";
              }
              if (rset.getString(17).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(17) + ",";
              }
              if (rset.getString(18).length() > 1) 
              {
                CustEmail = CustEmail + rset.getString(18) + ",";
              }
              i = SendEmail("Complain Escalation", "Final Complain Escalation", EmailText, CustEmail);
              if (i == 1) 
              {
                UpdateEscalationTable(rset.getInt(1), 3, conn);
              }
            }
          }
          rset.close();
          stmt.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a jar file that is required for connection in your lib folder
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Follow this link to open connection 
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/
Download the example from above link and then copy paste the sql jar files and use

 
Or
Download this directly from 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 2):

You miss the mysql jdbc connectior in your classpath.

Comment: where can you please specify more

Comment: @TabishHafeez How do you call your program?

Comment: by running the crontab file in linux

Comment: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/hosting/WEB-INF/classes/Hosting/ScheduleMessanger.bat

Comment: @TabishHafeez You can not call a `bat` on a linux system.

Comment: @TabishHafeez if my answer has helped you, feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Jens Suggested

> You miss the mysql jdbc connectior in your classpath.

**How to Resolve it ?**

find `.classpath` file in your project and add the `mysql jdbc connection` jar path in your .classpath file,

> Note: If you are modifying this file and you are not familiar with it
>   , So Be carefull else other error may also arise .

**Alternative option open the project in eclipse**

1. right click on `project --> build path --> configure build path`
2. A pop up will appear Go to `library tab --> Add jar --> Give Path to Your jar`
3. Build the Project again and bingo you are good to go

***Some suggestion regarding You code***

`newInstance() method` in the below mentioned line is not required ,

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Directly use

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Instead of declaring variables in single line like this

```
String Query = "";String Query1 = "";String EmailText = "";String CustEmail = "";
```

Declare them in seperate line which increases ***Readability***

```
String Query = "";
String Query1 = "";
String EmailText = "";
String CustEmail = "";
```

Instead of using `String` use `StringBuffer` because

```
String s = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

will ultimately becomes

```
String s = new StringBuffer().append("a").append("b").append("c").toString();
```

Comment: thanks for your precious time :) it helped alot. and i have modified my code according to what you said to me. its really helpful. I cant up vote your answer as i am new to this